# No module named "" error when loading the pickle file

Tags: jupyter, anaconda, pickle

I created a model and I saved it in a pickle file using the Algorithm SVR(Support Vector Regression)

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(model,open('carb patients data/Pickles/svr.pickle', 'wb'))
```

In jupyter notebook it gives an error

> can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

So I converted that jupyter file in to a .py file and downloaded it and executed using the Python Idle. Then it got saved in that particular location. But when I try to load my pickle file from another Jupyter Notebook it gives an error called,

> No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'

The code how i tried to load the pickle file,

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, flash, jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle as p
import json
from sklearn import ensemble
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/', methods=['POST'])
def makecalc():
  data = request.get_json()
  prediction = np.array2string(model.predict(data))

  return jsonify(prediction)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   modelfile = 'Clustering Patients/carb patients data/Pickles/svr.pickle'
   model = p.load(open(modelfile, 'rb'))
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Any thing I have done wrong or is it an issue in the Jupyter Notebook? How can I load my saved pickle file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [scikit-learn model persistence docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html), it may be better to use `joblib` instead:

Save model

```py
from joblib import dump

dump(model, 'filename.joblib')
```

Load model

```py
from joblib import load

model = load('filename.joblib')
```